# Why is image linked from i.imgur.com, although it's been added to i.stack.imgur.com?

Tags: support, images

I had a problem viewing second image in [@Karel's answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/586/are-there-reasons-to-use-colour-filters-with-digital-cameras/619#619) to "Are there reasons to use colour filters with digital cameras?".

When editing the answer, the image seems to be at https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LIQT.jpg and does exist there, but in HTML rendered from the post the image is referenced as [http://i.imgur.com/8LIQT.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/8LIQT.jpg) - which is not found.

**EDIT:** the image seems to have now appeared on main site. But still...

Why does Photo.SE use different image URL in HTML than specified in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered here:

[Images manually uploaded to Imgur are not displaying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734)

TL;DR there is some indeterminate edge condition around certain users who used imgur *without* using our official "upload" button in the editor.

Comment: Editing the post fixed the image links in HTML.